# "Wurde untersucht" oder "Wurden untersucht"?

Tags: grammaticality

Heißt es

> Dabei wurde als Erstes der Speicheraufbau sowie der Speicherzugriff untersucht

oder eher

> Dabei wurden als Erstes der Speicheraufbau sowie der Speicherzugriff untersucht

?

Answer (score 3):

Um die Kommentare und die Antwort hier nochmal auf einen Nenner zu bringen:

> Dabei wurden zu Beginn der Speicheraufbau sowie der Speicherzugriff untersucht.

wäre korrekt, da mehrere Dinge untersucht wurden. Im Gegensatz zu Schölnasts Aussage ist es jedoch sehr wohl möglich mehrere Dinge zu Beginn zu machen. Wenn man *wurde* nutzen würde, müsste der Satz eher wie folgt aufgebaut sein:

> Dabei wurde zu Beginn der Speicheraufbau sowie *nachfolgend* der Speicherzugriff untersucht.

Durch die zeitliche Trennung bezieht sich "*wurde*" zweimal auf ein Singular.

Comment: "sowie" ist nicht "und", sondern eher "und auch". Bei "und auch" kann meiner Meinung nach ruhig der Singular stehen.

Answer (score -1):

Der Satz an sich ist unsinnig (auf semantischer Ebene). *Als Erstes* kann nur eine der beiden Sachen untersucht werden (Highlander-Prinzip: Es kann nur einen geben), die andere Sache würde dann *als Zweites* untersucht werden. Besser wäre stattdessen die Formulierung »zu Beginn«, denn *zu Beginn* ist eine Phase, in der man gerne mal auch mehrere Aktivitäten ausführen kann.

Grammatisch ist der Fall aber klar: Wenn im Subjekt mehrere Dinge stehen, muss das Prädikat in seiner Pluralform stehen. Dabei ist es egal, ob im Subjekt ein Begriff im Plural steht oder, so wie hier, eine Liste mit zwei oder mehr Elementen.

Daher richtig:

> Dabei wurden zu Beginn der Speicheraufbau sowie der Speicherzugriff untersucht.

Comment: Wenn *zu Beginn* eine Phase bezeichnen kann, in der man gerne mal auch mehrere Aktivitäten ausführen kann, wieso sollte dann *als Erstes* nicht eine solche Phase bezeichnen können?

Comment: Wenn "Speicheraufbau sowie der Speicherzugriff" als eine zusammengehörende Sachen gemeint sind, ist der Satz nicht unsinnig und Singular kann verwendet werden.

Comment: Ich sehe das auch so wie @DavidVogt. _Als Erstes_ bezeichnet eine Phase im Prozess der Untersuchung. Der Gebrauch des Plurals ist dennoch korrekt.

Comment: Ich sehe es auch wie David. Als Erstes wurden alle 35 Einzelteile auf Vorhandensein und korrekte Ausführung überprüft. Als Zweites wurde das Gerät zusammengebaut. Also Ausführungsschritte, die ihrerseits wiederum aus mehreren Handgriffen bestehen können.